# what is the difference between >> and >>> operators in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

Running the following JavaScript code shows `63` in both cases:

```
  alert( 0xff >> 2 );
  alert( 0xff >>> 2 );
```

What is the differences between `>>` and `>>>`? Their results seem to be equal.

Comment: Why would you expect `8 >> 4` to be 2?

Comment: my bad it is 8/16, so that is indeed 0, but what about the diffrence between >> and >>> ? fixed the qeustion

Comment: @ZoZo123 I have rephrased your question, so that it's more to-the-point. I hope you don't mind it ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`>>` is a bitwise operator, which shift the bits to the right. Any bits at the right are lost.

```
 8 = 1000
     ^-->1
   = 0000 = 0
```

`>>>` does the similar thing as `>>`, but it's unsigned, which means that it ranges from 0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1 instead of +/- 2<sup>31</sup>-1.

To see the result of my first statement in action, let's use the bitwise operator to floor a number:

```
1.234 >> 0         =  1 // Ok, fraction lost
1.234 >>>0         =  1 // Ok, fraction lost
-1.23 >> 0         = -1 // Ok, fraction lost
-1.23 >>>0         = 4294967295 // (negative numbers are not within the range)

Math.pow(2,31) >> 0  = -2147483648 // 2^31 is out of range
Math.pow(2,31) >>> 0 = 2147483648
```

So, when the upper boundary of a range is exceeded, the calculation will continue at its lower range, and vice versa (eg `<<`). The following illustrates shows what happens when you use `n = (n + 1) >> 0`, and `>>> 0`, for `n` starting at the lowest boundary.

```
// Signed       Unsigned
     >>            >>>
-2147483647             0
-2147483646             1
...                   ...
 2147483646    4294967294
 2147483647    4294967295
-2147483647             0
-2147483646             1
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the [Unsigned Right Shift Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/342xfs5s%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

A few links:

- [Shift with zero fill](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040__Operators/ShiftRightZeroFill.htm)
- [Shift with sign](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040__Operators/ShiftRightwithSign.htm)